# SSL Certificate Verify Failed - Yahoo Finance API - Python

Tags: python, ssl, yahoo-finance, certifi

I am trying to fetch data from yahoo finance, but I am getting SSL error. The code is mentioned below:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/META", verify=True)
print(response.status_code)
```

Getting the following error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 847, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='query1.finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v8/finance/chart/META (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yudhveersingh/Desktop/Algo Trade/test", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/META", verify=True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='query1.finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v8/finance/chart/META (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))
```

I tried bypassing the verification process:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/META", verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
```

But I got a 429 error code:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1103: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'localhost'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
  warnings.warn(
429
```

Comment: Are you sure 429 error is related to verify=False? 429 is used when you issue too many request in short time. Try waiting a few minutes and try again.

Comment: SSL thing is just a warning: "InsecureRequestWarning" . Your issue is most likely due to rate limiting of the API you are working with. Hence the 429 status code. Or maybe rate limiting on users with limited authorization/verification.

Comment: *"Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'localhost'"* - where does this `localhost` comes from if you connect to `query1.finance.yahoo.com`?. Do you use some proxy which you don't tell us about?